# Attack Lab phases 4 and 5

Tags: assembly, x86-64, opcode, machine-code

In the particular version of Attack Lab that I am following, I have various codes in my farm that look like the following :

```
0000000000401a4c <getval_440>:
  401a4c:       b8 48 89 c7 c3          mov    $0xc3c78948,%eax
  401a51:       c3                      retq
```

On online walkthroughs, I have seen how in the above for example, if the 0x401a50th byte was a 90, it would mean NOP and hence I can directly assume that the operation from byte 401a4d onwards was performing `movq %rax, %rdi`, and hence we can take that byte onwards as our "gadget". However, in cases when a c3 is present in the place of 90, as in the code above, what does it mean? The only other piece of information I have is that a return instruction is encoded by a single c3. So, can i just assume the c3 at the end to be encoding a return instruction?

Comment: Yes, it is a `ret`. That means if you `call` your gadget it will do the `mov %rax, %rdi` and then return.

Comment: Duplicate of [c3 at the end of an opcode in Attack Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69747930).  I guess I should promote my comment to an answer there.